# How to use async calls in WPF event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, restsharp

I have this event handler in WPF with async call.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folderStructure = restApiProvider.GetFolderStructure();
}
```

Here is the implementation of `GetFolderStructure()`:

```
public async Task<IList<string>> GetFolderStructure()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.Get);
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<string>>(response.Content);
}
```

I need to get the data from `GetFolderStructure()` in order to continue in the app but this is the output I get:
[image]

If I add `folderStructure.Wait();` the call doesn't complete itself and the whole app get stuck. However if I change `var folderStructure = restApiProvider.GetFolderStructure();` to `restApiProvider.GetFolderStructure();` the call is completed immediately and stuck doesn't occure.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the calling method async and await the result:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folderStructure = await restApiProvider.GetFolderStructure();
}
```